# jQuery Validate Plugin - Display minlength "Characters to go" in error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I'm using the [jQuery Validate Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate forms on my website. I would like to change the default `minlength` message to show the number of characters STILL NEEDED in the field, and for this number to change as the user types in the `input` field.

For example, if the `minlength` rule is 15 characters, and there are 2 characters in the field, the error message would read `"Please enter at least 13 more characters."`

For the sake of simplicity, here's my jQuery. **All of the code below does not function as desired when put together, so I need a solution that DOES work**

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ac2T2/1/

Here's my code:

```
$('#contactForm').validate({
    rules: {
        contactName: {
            minlength: 15
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to add some code that does something like the following:

```
var numOfCharactersToGo = 15 - parseInt($('contactName').val().length);
```

and then in theory I could change my default jQuery message for `minlength` as shown here:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format('Please enter at least ' + numOfCharactersToGo + ' more characters.')
});
```

Comment: So what is the question/issue?

Comment: What I did above does not work.

Comment: would you mind whipping up a quick jsfiddle for your code?

Comment: Added fiddle to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Sparky's answer leading me in the right direction, here's the final answer in case anyone else wants the same functionality.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhRGA/8/

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var minChar = 15;
    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: minChar
            }
        },
        messages: {
            field1: {
                minlength: function () {
                    return [
                        (minChar - parseInt($('#field1').val().length)) +
                        ' more characters to go.'];

                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dynamically change `rules` or `messages` after the plugin has been initialized on the form, without using a built-in method for such changes.

There's only one way that I know about where you can *dynamically* over-ride any rules and messages after initialization.  That's with [the `rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).

```
$('#field').on('keyup', function () {  
    current = 15 - parseInt($(this).val().length);
    $(this).rules('add', {
        minlength: 15,
        messages: {
            minlength: current + " characters to go"
        }
    });
});
```

You'd need to call the above inside your `keyup` event handler function or whatever function you're using to dynamically count the characters.  The demo is crude and has some issues to overcome, but it shows that it *might* be possible.

**Very Crude DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZhRGA/5/**

Comment: That seems to work - I added it to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ac2T2/1/ BUT when it reaches 8 characters, it disappears for some reason? Ideas?

Comment: @AdamD, like I said, it has some issues. The method was never intended for this purpose.  But in this case, it seems to be my logic/math... like you are subtracting the remaining length from the current rule.  It always fails at the halfway point.

Comment: @AdamD, I declared it above the method.

Comment: I saw that. Oops... so there's no way for it to work as I intended? I feel like this is SO close

Comment: @AdamD, think about it... we're changing the rule itself... when the counter gets to 8, there are already 8 characters in the field and the rule is satisfied.  I tried using the same method to change the `message` rather than the rule but that did not work at all.

Comment: Only problem is that once it reaches `1` it is stuck, and the error doesn't clear?

Comment: @AdamD, try the `rules('remove')` method.  It's still not perfect, but this is as far as I've got:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZhRGA/4/

Comment: @AdamD, try something like `$(this).siblings('label.error').hide()`:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZhRGA/5/ ~ but it's still not validating the form properly for some reason.  I reported a weird bug at Github the other day where `rules('add')` broke the `number` rule only when the custom `messages` option was used.  Maybe that's a problem here too.

Comment: I tried just redefining the rule to set it to a value less than `current` if it was valid, but this didn't validate the field either.

Comment: @AdamD, I think you're stuck for now.  Like I said, [I know there's a bug that breaks certain rules when used with the `rules('add')` method, but only when the `messages` option is also used](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/668).  I think that's in play here.